# MomentJS beginner date validation fail

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to validate a date in string format with moment JS.

I use the `dd/mm/yy` format in pCalendar in ngPrime and the `stDate` is the value I get.

Here is my code snippet:

```
var stDate = '02/02/2021';
var stDateMoment = moment(stDate, 'dd/mm/yy');
```

I can not understand why the expression

```
stDateMoment.isValid()
```

returns a **false** value.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: The input format is `'DD/MM/YYYY'` with 4 x `Y`. See [format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Comment: The format probably should be `DD/MM/YYYY` as the format tokens are case-sensitive https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: Indeed, corrected, thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved my problem! Please post your comments as solution

Comment: @evolutionxbox please post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very almost there. The format tokens are case-sensitive, so using the lowercase `dd`, `mm`, and `yy` is not valid.

```js
const stDate = '02/02/2021';
const stDateMoment = moment(stDate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');

console.log(
  stDateMoment.isValid() 
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

For more information on this, please [read the momentjs string format documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

---

The docs also state that two `Y`s is for two-digit years, but four `Y`s is for four-digit years.

Comment: if I put the 'yyyy' in ngPrime pCalendar, I am getting a year like 20212021, that's why I was using just 'yy'. Thank you very much!

Comment: @AndrewT I'm glad I could be helpful

Answer (score 0):

creating a Date Object for your formatted date will solve the issue

```
var stDate = new Date("02/02/2021");
var stDateMoment = moment(stDate,"DD/MM/YY");
const validation = stDateMoment.isValid(); // true
```